# What did the presenter say here?

Tags: interpretation

This is in this [video](https://youtu.be/PudZNM276CY). The words I cannot make out is at 15 minute and 34 second. Here is the sentence:

> And human society though ????? that greed is taken on not just acquiring as much as possible, but acquiring as much as possible from other individuals.

There is not subtitles, so I have no idea what those words are. I have played the part at a slower pace to catch it, but to no avail.

Comment: You have mis-transcribed it. I really don't think you should be posting these things. We are not a transcription service. :)

Comment: Could you please tell me what transcription service I can use then?

Comment: You can ask in [chat]. transcription requests aren’t really in scope for the Q&A part of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She says

> **In** human **societies** though, **my perspective is** that greed **has** taken on not just acquiring as much as possible, but acquiring as much as possible **explicitly at the expense of** other individuals.

Seems to be a good documentary!

Answer (score 1):

????? = greed has taken on "not just acquiring as much as possible" but "acquiring as much as possible explicitly at the expense of other individuals, and I don't think that's something that you can apply to animals.".